# Node String not displaying

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to get a list of names within a Queue to display. 
When I call the toString from JOptionPane, it doesn't show anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public String toString() {

    String input = "";

    for(Node<T> current = endNode.getNext(); current != null; current = current.getNext()){


        input = input + current.toString() + "\n";

        endNode = current;
        current = current.getNext();


    }
    return input;
}
```

It weird because when I change the code to:

```
public String toString() {

    int counter = 0;
    String input = "";
    Node<T> current = endNode.getNext();
    // Loops until it goes through all stored nodes
    if(current != null){

        input = input + current + "\n";

        endNode = current;
        current = current.getNext();


    }

    return input;
}//end toString
```

It prints out the first name in the queue. Why does it work for the 'if' but not the 'for' loop?

EDIT : Here's my Node class:

```
public class Node<T> {

private T data;
private Node<T> next;

public Node(T data2, Node<T> next2) {
    data = data2;
    next = next2;
}

public String toString() {
    return data.toString();
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setData(T data2) {
    data = data2;
}


public void setNext(Node<T> next2) {
    next = next2;
}
```

It seems there is a toString here too..could that be the root of the problem?

Comment: You're calling `current.getNext()` too often (in the `for` ITER section and in the last statement of the loop),. I also don't see where `endNode` is initialized; are you sure `getNext()` starts returning the first element? To see at least some output, do `String input = "Result: ";` or something.

Comment: endNode is initialized from another java file called LinkedQueue. like so: static LinkedQueue<String> queue = new MyQueue<>(); . I omitted the current = current.getNext() from the for statement and left the one underneath it. When I used sysout (current), it looped through all the names just fine. EDIT : It skips the first name :l

Comment: Like @Kenney was saying try adding String input = "Result: "; to see if you get anything back

Comment: Woah... I don't get anything back... Why? I put String input = "Result: " exactly and nothing shows up in JOptionPane

Comment: By the way, I was told that endNode.getNext() is the front of the queue while endNode is the end of the queue.

Comment: Where are you calling toString() method from?

Comment: From my static void method displayMenu(String one, String two). the call looks like this JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, queue.toString());

Comment: there's probably a conflict between my java files. or i forgot to initialize something.

Comment: `if` is not a loop, of course it just run once

Comment: What is the type of private T data?

Comment: I know that haha, I was just wondering why it wouldn't work for the 'for' but only the 'if' one. There's no correlation whatsoever? :(

Comment: @Eleazar it's a String in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `if` variation is not working simply because `if` is not a loop.  I bet you are trying to do `while`

Bear in mind that

```
for(A;B;C){
    D;
}
```

can (mostly) be represented as

```
A;
while (B) {
    D;
    C;
}
```

so the correct way to make your for loop to a while loop is :

(Your original for loop)

```
// a bit strange that you start with the "endNode", are you sure it is not "startNode"?
// and starting with next node will cause `endNode` itself to be skipped 
// and is going to cause problem if endNode itself is null
for(Node<T> current = endNode.getNext()
    ; current != null
    ; current = current.getNext()){
    input = input + current.toString() + "\n";  // bad idea to do string concat in loop, use StringBuilder instead

    endNode = current;  // this one makes no sense and did nothing meaningful
    current = current.getNext();  // this is already in for-loop, 
                                  // having this is going to
                                  // roll-forward 2 nodes each loop
}
```

so I assume correct for loop should be

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Node<T> current = endNode
    ; current != null
    ; current = current.getNext()){
    sb.append(current).append("\n");
}
input = sb.toString();
```

Base on the for-to-while conversion method, the while loop should look like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Node<T> current = endNode;
while (current != null) {
    sb.append(current).append("\n");
    current = current.getNext();
}
input = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I'm sorry this is the other class I'm using which is why it is endNode http://pastebin.com/D0V9mR4y    I know the name sounds confusing.

Comment: sorry I cannot access pastebin now :P  Anyway, that shouldn't be the main point of the answer.  I believe you can digest the answer and use it the way you need  :)